# Error CS0120 when trying to enable or disable a toolstrip menu item

Tags: c#, winforms

While I was re-writing a program to C# this triggers an error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0120
>
> An object
>   reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
>   'Form1.quickLoadToolStripMenuItem'    NorthbridgeLauncher C:\NorthBridge-Launcher\NorthbridgeLauncher\SaveManager.cs  26

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(SaveFolderLocation))
         Form1.quickLoadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = (Directory.GetFiles(SaveFolderLocation, "*.isgsf").Length > 0);
    else
         Form1.quickLoadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    Close();
}
```

Even when I set the entire toolstrip to public doesn't work.

Comment: Change Form1 to the actual reference of the form that was instantiated.

Comment: Where is `button1_Click`? Is it in a different form from the toolstrip?

Comment: It's on the same form that the code is.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quick clear. You're trying to access a non-static variable

> quickLoadToolStripMenuItem

is not static.

Use the forms instance.

Comment: @stuartd So them the OP should use the forms instance to acess the toolstrip.

Comment: Agreed. But your advice to "make it static" is misleading.

Comment: In fact, when I've setted it to static on Form1's code, the designer gave me an error and it did not load it. Although how do you use the form's instance? (I'm asking it since I'm a beginner in this).

Comment: @acemod13 Well if button_click is a partial class of Form1. All you have to do is put quickLoadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = ...

If it's not a partial class, then you'll have to locate where you created an instance of Form1. Once you find the variable that contains the current instance, you will use the variable to access quickLoadToolStripMenuItem

Comment: And I get this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'Form' does not contain a definition for 'quickLoadToolStripMenuItem' and no extension method 'quickLoadToolStripMenuItem' accepting a first argument of type 'Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) NorthbridgeLauncher C:\Users\acemo\Source\Repos\NorthBridge-Launcher\NorthbridgeLauncher\SaveManager.cs 26

Comment: The error is quite clear. The variable hasn't been defined in 'Form' meaning that it must be defined in 'Form1'. The 'Form' class must be creating an instance of 'Form1' somewhere.

Comment: So, I need to do something like Form BaseForm1 = new Form1?

Comment: Could you please explain it in great detail? I have tried so many times in setting an instance that I could not do it. Form1 launches when the program starts up.